# 'module' object has no attribute 'DataReader

Tags: python-2.7

import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web # as we have to use only pandas function

```
    #Second, retrieve the data from, say, Google itself:
```

stock = web.DataReader('IBM',data_source='yahoo',start='01/01/2011', end='01/01/2013')

```
    # end of question 1
```

print type(stock) # Class Type is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

IBM_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(stock)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 2, in 
    import pandas.io.data as web # as we have to use only pandas function

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py", line 2, in 
    "The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package "

ImportError: The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package (pandas-datareader). After installing the pandas-datareader package (https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader), you can change the import `from pandas.io import data, wb` to `from pandas_datareader import data, wb`.

import pandas_datareader as web

stock = web.DataReader('IBM',data_source='yahoo',start='01/01/2011', end='01/01/2013')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    stock = web.DataReader('IBM',data_source='yahoo',start='01/01/2011', end='01/01/2013')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataReader'

change the import pandas.io.data as web to import pandas_datareader as web but now not able to get data plz suggest getting error 
'module' object has no attribute 'DataReader'

Comment: Did you try `dir(web)` to see what attributes it does have?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
DAX = data.DataReader(name='^GDAXI', data_source='yahoo',start='2000-1-1')
```